# Run a Google Script only weekdays every 15-minute, between certain hours - using time-based trigger?

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I have a google app script that I need to run every weekday only between 09:30 AM to 15:45 PM. I am not being able to add the minutes. I have a code that has the hours in it. My code is given below. I tried to add minutes with && but that is giving funny results.

```
function Record() {

var today = new Date();
  var day = today.getDay();
  
  var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']
  
  if(day == 6 || day == 0) {
    return;
  } else {

    var hour = today.getHours();
    var minute = today.getMinutes();
    if(hour < 10 || hour > 15) {
      return;
    }

  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source1 = ss1.getRange("Nifty!C28:K28");
  var destSheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Record 1");
  destSheet1.appendRow(source1.getValues()[0]);

  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source2 = ss2.getRange("Bank Nifty!C28:K28");
  var destSheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("Record 2");
  destSheet2.appendRow(source2.getValues()[0]);

  }
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

#### This is not exactly the time but it's pretty close

```
function Record(e) {
  if (e['day-of-week'] < 6 && e.hour > 9 && e.hour < 16) {
    const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const src1 = ss1.getRange("Nifty!C28:K28");
    var dsh1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Record 1");
    dsh1.appendRow(src1.getValues()[0]);

    var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var src2 = ss2.getRange("Bank Nifty!C28:K28");
    var dsh2 = ss2.getSheetByName("Record 2");
    dsh2.appendRow(src2.getValues()[0]);
  }
}

//only creates one trigger for the handlerfunction
function createTimeBasedTrigger() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "Record").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("Record").timeBased().everyMinutes(15).create();
  }
}
```

Comment: What about the 30 minutes past 9 AM or 45 minutes past 3 PM. Any clue on how to start the function after hh:mm or stop before hh:mm ??