# Run Google appscript weekdays between times and every x minute

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, scheduled-tasks

I would like to run an Apps Script during office hours, every 15  min.

I found a script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71028932/run-a-google-script-only-weekdays-every-15-minute-between-certain-hours-using) however it gives me the error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'day-of-week')

```
function Record(e) {
  if (e['day-of-week'] < 6 && e.hour > 8 && e.hour < 17) {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Alert message");
  }
}

//only creates one trigger for the handlerfunction
function createTimeBasedTrigger() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "Record").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("Record").timeBased().everyMinutes(15).create();
  }
}
```

Could anyone point me in the direction what I need to do?

I tried

```
['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']
```

but it dindn't work.

Comment: I closed the question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74109026/ as this question explains the error. By the other hand, the question has several problems.  It's fair to assume that you are running the question from the script editor, so it's unclear if you know how to create time driven triggers and if you want to this programmatically or manually. Also your script will not work with time drivent triggers as it opens an alert but time driven triggers hasn't access the the Google Sheets UI so if you want to show an alert every 15 mins you should use client-side code.

Answer (score -1):

You can check day of week and current time using Date class.

```js
const now = new Date();
const dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
const hour = now.getHours();

const isBusinessHour = dayOfWeek < 6 && dayOfWeek > 0 && hour >= 8 && hour <= 17;

document.querySelector("#answer").innerText = isBusinessHour && "Yes!" || "No!"
```

```html
<h3>Are we currently in business hours?</h3>
<h4 id="answer"></h4>
```

So you just need to use this logic in your `Record()` function.

```
function Record(e) {
  const now = new Date();
  const dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
  const hour = now.getHours();

  const isBusinessHour = dayOfWeek < 6 && dayOfWeek > 0 && hour >= 8 && hour <= 17;
  if (isBusinessHour) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Alert message");
  }
}
```